# Implement google place search and save marker to database in google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

**What I want to achieve:** 
I want to display a search box in google map. When a user search a location, result is displayed in map box. On the map, when a user RightClick, I want to store the marker in database.

**Resource I tried to implement**

storing marker to database:
https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/10/google-map-v3-editing-saving-marker-in-database

displaying search box in map
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

I tried to implement these two as one: here is my minimal code

```js
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(27.7172, 85.3240);
var map;

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', map_initialize);

function map_initialize() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: mapCenter,
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {

    create_marker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function create_marker(MapPos) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: MapPos,
    map: map
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

With this code when I right click on the map, nothing happens i.e. neither the marker shows nor any error.

Answer (score 0):

The `map` variable needs to be accessible from your `create_marker` function, therefore you declared it outside of your other functions. But **also** inside the `map_initialize` function. Remove the `var` declaration from there and it will work.

I have **edited** your original question to include a **[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** which means that I removed 90% of your code to **keep only what you were after**: adding a marker on right click.

Please take that as a suggestion for how to write your next questions.

```js
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(27.7172, 85.3240);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', map_initialize);

function map_initialize() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: mapCenter,
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {

    create_marker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function create_marker(MapPos) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: MapPos,
    map: map
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```